# What functions in Adobe Illustrator to use to get these effects?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

How can I make on my own? What functions I need to use in Adobe Illustrator for 'waving' words?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I would guess envelope distort with a mesh over a block of the text.  It would be slightly putzy to set up the mesh, but doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use *Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Mesh*. Set the number of rows the same as the number of lines of text, and columns to 1. Then edit the mesh using the Direct Selection Tool <kbd>A</kbd>.

In the example below, to get this to work better, I also converted the text to outlines and added an invisible box around the text and grouped them, so that the mesh fitted between the lines of text exactly.

Example

[image]

Comment: Cheers mate. Idea to add an invisible box really helped. I used the rotate effect in 3d to give it perspective. Here's what I made quickly https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVqTe.jpg

Comment: Thanks! That's helped